# how to create a searchable and selectable list view in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a searchable list View but I also want to select multiple items from list view and also store selected items in a list in Flutter?

how can I create a searchable list view that search items?
and also selects items from the same list view in flutter?

and selected items will be stored in list and display on screen?

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {

  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  var showError = false;
  List<String> subjectListOnSearch = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return   Scaffold(
      
      appBar: AppBar(
       
        title: Text(
          'Select Subject',
         
        ),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(45),
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 7),
           
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  subjectListOnSearch = subjectList
                      .where((element) => element
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .contains(value.toLowerCase()))
                      .toList();
                  if (value.trim().isEmpty) {
                    showError = false;
                  } else {
                    showError = true;
                  }
                });
              },
              controller: _textEditingController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixIcon: Visibility(
                  visible: showError,
                  child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.close,
                          color: Colors.blue),
                      onPressed: () {
                        subjectListOnSearch.clear();
                        _textEditingController.clear();
                        setState(() {
                          _textEditingController.text = '';
                        });
                      }),
                ),
                hintText: 'Search Subject',
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                 
                ),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: _textEditingController.text.isNotEmpty &&
          subjectListOnSearch.isEmpty
          ? Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.search_off,
              color: Colors.red,
              size: 100,
            ),
            Text(
              'No Results Found',
             
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
          : ListView.builder(
          itemCount:
          _textEditingController.text.isNotEmpty
              ? subjectListOnSearch.length
              : subjectList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 15,
                top: 15,
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 25,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                  child: Icon(
                      MaterialCommunityIcons
                          .book_open_page_variant,
                     ),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  _textEditingController.text.isNotEmpty
                      ? subjectListOnSearch[index]
                      : subjectList[index],
                
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to make your text selectable in Listview you should use **`SelectableText()`** Widget, Check [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText-class.html) in the documentation and for search implementation you should see this video of andrew and matt they have explained it in the most easiest way possible [flutter's Search Support](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wm3OiFBZ2xI&t=2163s).